# TCP Socket HTTP GET Request Content-Length > 0 but not returning actual Content

Tags: java, spring, sockets, http

I am trying to query a REST API service hosted on a Tomcat/Spring Boot application using a TCP Socket instead of an HTTPClient as I cannot use an HTTPClient. I am able to successfully open the Socket, send the request, and receive data from the server but there is never any body or content returned in the server response. If I use a web browser to query the same URL it works just fine. Here is the program I am using to make the request:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketClient {

    public SocketClient() {
        String hostname = "192.168.10.104";
        int port = 8080;

        try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port)) {

            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, false);

            writer.println("GET /company/1 HTTP/1.1");
            writer.println("Host: " + hostname + ":" + port);
            writer.println("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36");
            writer.println("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
            writer.println("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9");
            writer.println("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
            writer.println("Connection: close");
            writer.println();
            writer.flush();

            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            String line;

            while (!(line = reader.readLine()).equals("")) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());

        }

    }
}
```

The server responds with the following data:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 55
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 15:45:00 GMT
Connection: close
```

The response indicates that there should be some content based on the Content-Length, but I never actually receive the content itself. Is it possible to do this? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You stop reading when you find an empty line. There's an empty line that separates headers from content, so you're just not reading the content.

readLine returns null when the server closes the connection. Change your loop to

```
while (!(line = reader.readLine()) == null)
```

Comment: Thanks Joni, I changed the loop and it does work but what is happening now is that it prints the original data I posted, then after about 30s (which I assume is some sort of timeout) it finally gets and prints the content. Looking at Wireshark it prints the content when it receives a final ACK from the server. Do you know if there is anyway to make this happen faster?

Comment: You can try telling the server you won't send more requests with `socket.shutdownOutput()` - maybe that will convince tomcat to close the connection once it's sent the response. Or you can implement more of the HTTP spec: parse the content-length header and stop reading when you have read that many *bytes* of the body.

Comment: If the content happens to be ASCII, this will read 55 bytes: `char[] content = new char[55]; for (int i = 0; i < 55; i += reader.read(content, i, 55-i));` If you have non-ASCII characters it becomes very hard to read an exact number of bytes, and this is why http client libraries exist

Comment: From the response headers you can see that the returned content is encoded in UTF-8. But you're using an InputStreamReader, which by default will decode using the client's default charset. So if the server sends anything that is not pure ASCII, and your default charset isn't UTF-8, you'll be in trouble.
As Joni above hinted these things are not completely trivial. If the server was using any encoding not compatible with ASCII then you'd have to first read the headers using ASCII, then read the content using whatever charset was specified by the server.